# Send Text from android app to pc browser through USB connected device in android studio

Tags: android, web-services, web

**Explaination:**

I have connected my smartphone to Android Studio using usb debugging for testing android app. And I want to send the text from application to the pc browser using Server like Apache Tomcat. Can Anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're facing and what steps you've taken to attempt to fix it?

Comment: Sure @Pants .. I want to create a connection for sending text or sensor data from android phone to PC Browser. For the same purpose I am creating an application in android studio, and for testing that application I have connected my phone to pc via usb. So whenever user will open the app in smartphone. the app will send some textual data to PC, where the phone is connected to same PC via usb debugging. I am not able to understand how to  send it. I tried for Asynchronous http client api. but it is for showing browser data on app which is not the result I want.